# Force to start python script with python exe to parse parameters

Tags: python

I am having trouble to start a python script and get the parameters I send to the script.

[image]

As you can see if I start the following test script with python comand,  it works, if not, well, no arguments are passed to the script :/

```
import optparse
import sys

oOptParse = optparse.OptionParser()

oOptParse.add_option("--arg", dest="arg", help="Test param")
oOptParse.set_default("arg", None)

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    oOptParse.print_help( )
    sys.exit( 1 )
aOptions = oOptParse.parse_args( )
oOptions =  aOptions[0]

print (oOptions.arg)
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: side note: optparse is deprecated, you should use argparse instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put shebang in the beginning of the python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make the file executable by:

```
chmod +x test.py
```

then type:

```
./test.py --arg hello
```

Under Windows system, you may do the above under Cygwin, or associate extension .py to Python by:

```
C:\> assoc .py=Python.File
C:\> ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.

It was a problem on registry settings the following key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
```

was set to

```
"C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1"
```

but should be

```
"C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: That's what i'm doubting: you missed arguments in file association. `ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\python.exe "%1" %*` should fix that too.